# How to do multiple inserts into sybase from c# at once

Tags: c#, sql, sap-ase

I am new to sybase db. I am trying inset multiple rows  using following code

```
string sql="INSERT INTO dbo.table1 (c1,c2,c3)
     VALUES ('C1','c2','c2'); INSERT INTO dbo.table1 (c1,c2,c3)
     VALUES ('C1','c2','c2'); ";


                Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand cmd = new Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 30 * 60;`enter code here`
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and i am getting the error "Incorrect syntax near ';'."  at the end of the first statement?  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any insert statements above. Did you post your full code snippet?

Comment: What about to show the value of that `sql`

Comment: Does Sybase require GO instead of ;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out   there is no need for  ; or GO. Thanks a lot for the input